# How to send DELETE request to server with Json data using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have to send a http DELETE request to a server. The type has to be JSON, and the object looks like this:

```
{ "id": "value"}
```

My first approach was the following code, but so far it doesn't work:

```
$http.delete('http://blabla/server/house', {"id": "value"}).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            //Redirect to index.html
            $location.path('/'); 
        });
```

What would a working solution look like?

Comment: The syntax is: `$http.delete(url, [config])`, not `$http.delete(url, [data])`

Answer (score 4):

As @KevinB pointed out, config is the second parameter.

```
var obj = { "id": "value"};
var config = { data: JSON.stringify(obj) };
$http.delete('http://blabla/server/house', config).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //Redirect to index.html
        $location.path('/'); 
    });
```

Comment: This is the error:TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'method' of {"id":"552e638a057995402fb9e329"}

Comment: which line are you getting this error. is your ID field being populated correctly? The theory behind this method is you create a javascript object the standard way. you then use stringify to parse that object to JSON, which you can then send back to the server. are you getting the error on the first line or the second?

Comment: also, you aren't using 'strict mode' by any chance are you?

Comment: @Asher Why, would that be a bad thing?

Comment: strict mode places typed restrictions on your script so you would do it differently. if you aren't, in my experience, this happens when you allocate undefined to a property

Comment: @Asher That error also happens when you try to assign to a property of a string, which is what is happening here. The syntax is: `$http.delete(url, [config])`, not `$http.delete(url, [data])`. Angular is taking the config object (in your case, a string) and is trying to add a `method` property to it.

Comment: Though, to be fair, you're right, that only happens in strict mode. outside of strict mode that error gets silently ignored.

Comment: Good spot. So you would do $http.delete(url, { params: obj }).success...... ? Obviously this is just an id so could be added as a url param but if it was a complex object, params is the parameter in the object which angularjs reads?

Comment: I would do `{data: JSON.stringify(obj)}` though i'm not sure if the JSON.stringify is even needed. the `DELETE` method generally doesn't have content, so i'm not sure if angular does anything different due to that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just pass the param as part of the query params. Something like this:

```
var config = {
   params: {
     yourServerSideParamName: JSON.stringify({'id': 'value' })
   }
};

$http.delete('blabla/server/house', config).success(function(data){
   $location.path('/'); 
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ohh, as I doooon't like people who decrease reputation without any explanations :/

Comment: *"The type has to be JSON"*

Comment: @KevinB. You are right. I haven't paid attention on that. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$http({
            method: 'DELETE',
            url: 'http://blabla/server/house',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'id': 'value'
            })
        }).success(function (results) {
            console.log(results);
            //Redirect to index.html
            $location.path('/'); 
        });
```