# pass a form object to http delete method using Angular

Tags: java, angular, web-services, web

I have a form object on the server side and on the UI side in sync. I use this form object to specify the values using which some server side computation takes place. For example the simplest form declaration is

```
export interface EmployeeForm {
    name:string;
    id:number;
}
```

The corresponding Java class

```
 class EmployeeForm {
   String name;
   Integer id;
}
```

When I call the service side method for get/post/put , I am able to send the form object from WebUI.
However I don't see similar option to send the form object when calling delete using HttpClient.delete method. On the server side, the API to handle delete request handles request from other server side components (for example some commands using SpringShell command utility) and so I prefer reusing the API. Do I need to develop new rest methods specific to UI request? Any pointers will be helpful since I did not get a solution so far. If you need additional details to understand my issue then please let me know.

Comment: i would just send an id for deletion - dnt really understand what the question is..? If backend doesnt have such an endpoint available yes you should create it.

Comment: I cannot specify the id since there might be multiple entries to delete based on certain critteria.. for example..delete all employees whose name starts with "A" and in that case the number field will be null. As I said, I want to mimic the way, the command line utility work , in WebUI preferrably reusing the existing rest API

Comment: then you can define an endpoint deleteAllStartingWithLetterX and send the letter. It feels like you want to bring too much logic into frontend, the task of frontend is to target narrowly defined endpoints with all the database interaction logic being defined in backend.

Comment: in any case by now this is too abstract - stackoverflow is for concrete question and concrete answers, not coming up with a general approach that fits all ur requirements

Comment: Can you please let me know what is missing from the perspective of concrete question so that I take care of it for future posts to make it more meaningful. Basically all I am trying to do is send a form object from my webUI to the backend rest service. The same logic works for other rest service like get/post/put etc but not delete

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653430/how-to-send-delete-request-to-server-with-json-data-using-angularjs - does this help? just send json ( iam sure u can easily transform form to json) and on the backend (especially java backend) easily turn that json into any object and delete whatever is needed

Comment: thanks.. this is helpful.. for some reason, I did not get this, while looking for answer